# Cloudfoundry: Images stored in database not displaying when app is running on cloudfoundy

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I have a simple Grails application that is working fine when deployed to my local Tomcat server. However, when I deploy to Cloudfoundry the images saved to the database are not displaying. Googling about the solution has only revealed that on Cloudfoundry you cannot (or not supposed to) use the local file system to store image files but I am using the database and writing to main memory (output stream) in my controller. Anyone help.

Here is a portion of the code:

//Picture domain class

```
class Picture {
    byte[] image
    String mimeType
    String name
    static belongsTo = ...

    static constraints = {
        name(maxSize:20, )
        image(maxSize:3145728)
        ....
    }
    String toString(){
        ...
    }
}


//Picture controller
def image = {

    def picture = Picture.get(params.id)

    if(!picture || !picture.image){
        ...
    }
    else{
        response.setContentType(picture.mimeType)
        response.setContentLength(picture.image.size())
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(picture.image);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

//In my gsp
< img width="128" height="96" class="image" src="${createLink(controller:'picture', action:'image', id:pictureInstance.ident())}" />

Thank you.

Comment: Seems good. Have you had a look at the logs (`vmc logs yourappname`) What do you get exactly? Do you get a 404? Do the content-length and mime-type get set? Also, can you try using the tunneling feature (http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html) to make sure the bytes for your images are actually in the db?

Comment: Thanks @ebottard for the info about tunneling with caldecott. I managed to install and ran the following query to get the shown results: => select mime_type,length(image) from picture;
 mime_type  | length
------------+--------
 image/jpeg |  41725
 image/jpeg |  27280
 image/jpeg |  68049
 image/jpeg | 108037
(4 rows)

Comment: and there are no errors in the logs when i run cf-logs from the grails cloudfoundry plugin. The only logs so far are from KickstartFilters.groovy: picture.list: [action:list, controller:picture]
picture.image: [id:9074, action:image, controller:picture]
picture.image: [id:9075, action:image, controller:picture]
picture.image: [id:9073, action:image, controller:picture]
picture.image: [id:9081, action:image, controller:picture]

Comment: OK. So next step: what do you get in terms of http response: 404? 200? What about the headers that your code is supposed to set, do you see them. One great option for troubleshooting this kind of situation is to use Micro Cloud Foundry (http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/infrastructure/overview.html, look at 2nd bullet): you can attach a debugger to it.

Comment: Problem is gone. I switched database services from PostgreSql to mysql. Seems image wasn't being saved properly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are having troubles with your query. Why don't you change your db from postgreSql to MySQL and see if the problem still occurs. I don't believe the issue here is wit the RDBMS service.